# how to perform function on all files in a directory or just a single file based on args, in python

Tags: python, loops

I have a small script i'm working on which "shreds" a single file (zeros the bytes of the file), and I am trying to make it so that I can shred every file in a directory based on if it receives a -file or -directory flag/arg via the command line.
It's working fine for single files but i am getting a:

`IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] 'Path/To/Directory' error when trying to use it on all files in a directory`. I have tried a few ways of arranging the loops so that they work but none have so far. I am hoping someone here can help me to correct this.

I have `argparser` setup so that `-F file, -D directory, -s srcpath, -i iterations` and anything to do with bar is just my progress bar which shows how far into the process the script is while running.

Here is my code:

```
parser= argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-F', '--file', action=store_true)
parser.add_argument('-D', '--directory', action=store_true)
parser.add_argument('-s', '--source', required=True, type=str)
parser.add_argument('-i', '--iterations', required=True, type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()

bar = Bar ("Progress: ", max=args.iterations)
srcpath = "path/to/file/"

def shredfile(source, filebytes):
    with open(source, 'r+b') as f:
        byte = f.read(1)
        while byte:
            f.write(filebytes)
            byte = f.read(1)

zeros = ("0000000").encode('UTF-8')

if args.file:
    x=0
    for x in range (args.iterations):
        shredfile(srcpath, zeros)
        bar.next()
    bar.finish()
    print("Completed")

if args.directory:
    for d in os.listdir(srcpath):
        x=0
        for x in range (args.iterations):
            shredfile(srcpath, zeros)
            bar.next()
        bar.finish()
        print("Completed")
```

Comment: What is `args`. The return value of [`argparse.ArgumentParser().parse_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser)?

Comment: Where is `bar` defined?

Comment: Can you post the _full_ traceback you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns  file names in the directory

```
for f in os.listdir(srcpath):
  full_path = os.path.join(f, srcpath)
  ...
    shredfile(full_path, zeros)
  ...
  print("Completed")
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfect, fixed the problem straight away once implemented

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you cannot shred a directory but only individual files.

```
shredfile(os.path.join(srcpath, d), zeros)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this answer is correct as well as the one above, problem has been fixed now. I appreciate your help very much @dnozay

Answer (score 0):

This would be a proper way to do this. You just have to add in your parts like progress bar and argument parsing.
You also need to add some try-except blocks to control what happens upon OSErrors like permission denied and similar stuff.

```
import sys
import os

def shredfile (source, filebytes=16*"\0"):
    f = open(source, "rb")
    f.seek(0, 2)
    size = f.tell()
    f.close()
    if len(filebytes)>size:
        chunk = filebytes[:size]
    else:
        chunk = filebytes
    f = open(source, "wb")
    l = len(chunk)
    n = 0
    while n+l<size:
        f.write(chunk)
        n += l
    # Ensure that file is overwritten to the end if size/len(filebytes)*len(filebytes) is not equal to size
    chunk = filebytes[:size-f.tell()]
    if chunk: f.write(chunk)
    f.close()

def shreddir (source, filebytes=16*"\0", recurse=0):
    for x in os.listdir(source):
        path = os.path.join(source, x)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            shredfile(path, filebytes)
            continue
        if recurse:
            shreddir(path, filebytes, 1)

def shred (source, filebytes=16*"\0", recurse=0):
    if os.path.isdir(source):
        shreddir(source, filebytes, recurse)
        return
    shredfile(source, filebytes)

if len(sys.argv)>1:
    print "Are you sure you want to shred '%s'?" % sys.argv[-1],
    c = raw_input("(Yes/No?) ").lower()
    if c=="yes":
        shred(sys.argv[-1])
# Here you can iterate shred as many times as you want.
# Also you may choose to recurse into subdirectories which would be what you want if you need whole directory shredded
```